# iOS/SQL: Add missing columns/ remove missing columns automatically to a table after an app update?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite, fmdb

Currently, I've create a table like so.

```
[self.fmDataBase executeUpdate:@"create table test (id integer primary key autoincrement, test text);"];
```

This works well, however in the future I  am going to need more columns for my table. It will look like so.

```
[self.fmDataBase executeUpdate:@"create table test (id integer primary key autoincrement, test text, test1 text);"];
```

Not completely sure on how to handle the situation. As time goes by I will need to add columns , remove columns or even change the name of the column. Am I suppose to do something like this

```
 if (version_1.1) {
     [self.fmDataBase executeUpdate:@"alter table test add test1 text"];
    } else if (version_1.2) {
     [self.fmDataBase executeUpdate:@"alter table test add test2 text"];
    } else if (version_1.3) {
     [self.fmDataBase executeUpdate:@"alter table test add test3 text"];
    }
```

Or is there a way around this by somehow comparing queries and making changes to it automatically? I want to make sure the App doesn't break when the user updates the App.  Seems like so far I have to manually update it for each app version.

Comment: Keep in mind that a user may skip a few updates so you need to handle updating from several versions back to the latest version as well.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414930/ios-method-on-app-update and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347455/ios-rolling-out-app-updates-keeping-user-data-intact-when-db-update-required?s=1|1.1056

Comment: @rmaddy. That is true. It seems like anytime I alter the database, I need to check the previous versions to make sure it is still working correctly. For example, if user goes from 1.1 to 1.3, I have to modify the if statement to include test 2 and test 3 column as well. Seems like the best solution to avoid a lot of complication in my situation is to keep up with the last two versions. Any versions older than that I will delete the db and make the user login and resync data again.  Most users seem to be using the previous two versions so I will satisfy the majority. Is that a good idea?

Comment: @Weakman10122 FWIW forcefully logging your users out is a bad idea - they *hate* it! Much better to find a way to upgrade seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about FMDB but ... if you use CoreData, it handles this automatically for you. As long as it has a record of each of your data model versions it will migrate ***any*** previous version of your database to the latest on startup.

When you initialise your persistent store coordinator, give it these flags:

```
NSDictionary *migrationOptions =@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@(YES),
                                  NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@(YES)};
```

For simple increments in databases (e.g. adding/removing tables and fields, not relational stuff) this is sufficient and works perfectly.